# remoteLink deprecated in Grails 2.4, now what?

Tags: ajax, grails

I noticed in Grails 2.4 documentation (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html), it mentioned the remoteLink tag is now deprecated.

But I don't understand the second part of the warning:

"Applications may provide their own Ajax tags and/or Javascript plugins may provide Ajax tags of their own".

So it will be simply removed so we shouldn't use it at all?  What is the replacement for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a way to use ajax without these deprecated tags? Its highly frustrating to have very important and critical functionality  deprecated with no alternative documented anywhere.  If anyone has found a solution, please let us know how to use ajax now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, they're removing the tags because they don't add much value, and instead contribute to bad design patterns - they're too low level. It's usually best to play within whatever Javascript frameworks you're using, and make higher level tags that make the AJAX calls for a purpose, rather than having a Grails tag JUST for making an AJAX call.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/IXvqDUr6CIE
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grails-dev-discuss/4yesijtFSB4